# how do i make my code wait before deleting a message (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I want to delete the bot's message after 5 seconds but I'm not sure how to do that. the message I want to delete is   `message.channel.send(sender + ' IS A NAUGHTY BOY');`   . I know how to delete the message I just don't know how to make it so that it waits 5 seconds before deleting it. the code is below.

```
 if (msg.includes('swear1') || msg.includes('swear2') || msg.includes('swear3') || msg.includes('swear4') || msg.includes('swear5') || msg.includes('swear6')) {
 message.delete();
 message.author.send('**Please refrain yourself from swearing on this server, Thanks**' );
  message.channel.send(sender + ' IS A NAUGHTY BOY'); // this is the message i want to delete after 5 seconds
 console.log(sender + ' Just Said ' + msg.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: Use setTimeout to delete the message set to 5000

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the timeout to the .delete method [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)

```
message.delete(5000);
```

would do the job.

Comment: i forgot to mension that i have this in my code    
       if (sender.id === '432598139640479745') {
       return;
    }

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send a message and then delete that message after 5 seconds you need to use Promises to get the message that was sent and after that delete it.

```
message.channel.send(sender + ' IS A NAUGHTY BOY')
    .then(newMessage => newMessage.delete(5000));
```

This is gonna send the message, and after was sent will trigger the .then promise. You will get the new message object to do whatever you want with it.

Documentation:

- [`message.channel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)
- [`message.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to wait some seconds to do a function, use setTimeout Method.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    //Code
 }, 5000); //time in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js updated this is now

```js
message.delete({timeout: 5000})
```